# Rendering Unity across multiple monitors

Tags: unity, rendering

At the moment I am trying to get unity to run across 2 monitors. I've done some research and know that this is, strictly, possible. There is a workaround where you basically have to fluff your window size in order to get unity to render across both monitors.

What I've done is create a new custom screen resolution that takes in the width of both of my monitors, as seen in the following image, its the 3840 x 1080:

[image]

How ever, when I go to run my unity game exe that size isn't available. All I get is the following:

[image]

My custom size should be at the very bottom, but isn't. Is there something I haven't done, or missed, that will get unity to take in my custom screen size when it comes to running my game through its exe?

Oddly enough, inside the unity editor, my custom screen size is picked up and I can have it set to that in my game window:

[image]

Is there something that I have forgotten to do when I build and run the game from the file menu? Has someone ever beaten this issue before?

Comment: Did you ask the same Question directly to the unity developer platform? ( http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/309819/getting-unity-to-render-across-multiple-monitors.html )

Comment: I did, yes. My thinking was some users wouldn't know about that place and that some unity developer platform users wouldn't know about here.

Comment: Any update on if my answer has helped?

Comment: Oh - sorry man. Your was the first answer I got in 9 months :) I managed to get it working in the end. Basically doing what you suggested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are ways of emulating the resolution and you are on the right tracks with your customised resolution in nVidia for your two monitors (as this is the way I have done it and made it work.)

You can use some third party tools to enable a dual screen setup in your Unity game. This unfortunately will not be something that will be packaged with your Unity3D game and so is not the most conventional solution for anyone that plays the game without these applications, however it is a workable solution.

The details I found in someones answer on the Unity Answers board where they were attempting to use multiple video outputs instead of using the Normalised Vieport Rectangles on one output spanning multiple monitors:

[Using Multiple Monitors Video Outputs](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/11350/using-multiple-monitors-video-outputs.html)

In order to acheive a custom resolution when you are running the game, to make your workaround a little more flexible for different multi monitor setups you can try to use the [Screen.SetResolution](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Screen.SetResolution.html) method to set the game to your custom resolutions. I am not sure if this will span your multiple monitors however so I'm not confident on its compatibility yet. I will test this out on my own project when I can.

Let me know if this helps or if you have any solutions already.